# Como criar playlist de áudio aleatório?

Tags: javascript, html5, html5-audio

Preciso de algo parecido com isso

```
function next() 
{ 
Url = new Array; 
Url[0] = "/mp3/001.mp3"; 
Url[1] = "/mp3/002.mp3"; 
Url[2] = "/mp3/003.mp3"; 
Url[3] = "/mp3/004.mp3"; 

Link = Math.floor(Math.random() * Url.length); 

} 


<audio autoplay="autoplay" onended="next()">
<source src="Url[Link]" type="audio/mpeg">
navegador não suporta áudio em HTML5.</audio>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você chegou perto, faltou fazer as interações entre o JavaScript e o HTML, bem como a chamada das funções do elemento `audio`.

Veja no código abaixo como é simples:

**HTML**

```
<audio id="player">
  O seu navegador não suporta áudio em HTML5.
</audio>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
/* Objects */
var _player = document.getElementById('player');

/* Aplication */
var tracks = [
  '1.mp3',
  '2.mp3',
  '3.mp3',
  '4.mp3',
  '5.mp3'
];

function playNext() {
  var track = tracks[Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks.length)];

  _player.src = track;
  return _player.play();
}

/* Events */
window.addEventListener('load', playNext);
_player.addEventListener('ended', playNext);
```

Você pode ver em funcionamento no link http://codepen.io/caio/pen/smyac, mas lembre-se de alterar o caminho dos arquivos de áudio.

Comment: Esse underline antes do player (`_player`) é uma convenção?

Comment: Não @Patrick, particularmente gosto de diferenciar variáveis de aplicação de variáveis de DOM quando utilizo Vanilla JS. :)

Answer (score 4):

O que acho legal nesses casos de *random playlist* é ir removendo os elementos já tocados da array, assim não arrisca repetir. E quando esvaziar a array, popular ela de volta com a array original.

Fiz uma adaptação do [código do Caio Tarifa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/34185/como-criar-playlist-de-%C3%A1udio-aleat%C3%B3rio/34193#34193) demonstrando a idéia: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/brasofilo/gqpwpb2d/).

Para [clonar a array](http://davidwalsh.name/javascript-clone-array) usa-se:

```
tracks_clone = tracks.slice(0);
```

A cada música tocada, eliminar o elemento:

```
tracks_clone.splice(randnum, 1);
```

E antes de começar a tocar, conferir se o clone já está vazio e popular de novo em caso positivo:

```
if( tracks_clone.length === 0 ) {
    tracks_clone = tracks.slice(0);
}
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="now"></div>
<audio preload="none" id="player" controls="controls"></audio>
<button id="next">next</button>
<p id="playlist"></p>
```

JS

```
var _now = document.getElementById('now'),
    _player = document.getElementById('player'),
    _next = document.getElementById('next'),
    _playlist = document.getElementById('playlist'),
    tracks_clone,
    mp3uri = 'http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/',
    tracks = [
        'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2005.mp3',
        'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2006.mp3',
        'Commercial%20DEMO%20-%2006.mp3',  
    ];

function playNext() {
    if( tracks_clone.length === 0 ) {
        tracks_clone = tracks.slice(0);
    }
    var randnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tracks_clone.length);
    var track = tracks_clone[randnum];
    _now.innerHTML = '<b>Random selected</b>: #' + randnum + '<br><b>Playing</b>: ' + decodeURIComponent(track).replace('.mp3','');
    tracks_clone.splice(randnum, 1);
    _playlist.innerHTML = ' - ' + decodeURIComponent(tracks_clone.join('<br> - '));
    _player.src = mp3uri + track;
    return _player.play();
}

function initPlayer() {
    tracks_clone = tracks.slice(0);
    _player.addEventListener('ended', playNext);
    _next.addEventListener('click', playNext, false);
    playNext();
}

window.addEventListener('load', initPlayer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eu fiz desse jeito, ai toda vez que apertar o botão "proximo" ele vai carregar uma musica nova

```js
function id(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id)
}

function init() {
  var container = id('fundo-controles');
  var ctr = id('som');
  var play = id('play');
  var pause = document.getElementById('pause');
  var vmais = document.getElementById('vmais');
  var vmenos = document.getElementById('vmenos');
  var mudou = id("proxi");
  if (!Modernizr.audio) {
    container.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    play.addEventListener('click', function() {
      ctr.play();
      ctr.volume = 1;
    }, false);

    pause.addEventListener('click', function() {
      ctr.pause();
    }, false);

    vmais.addEventListener('click', function() {
      ctr.play();
      ctr.volume += 0.25;

    }, false);
    mudou.addEventListener('click', function() { //usado para passar a musica
      var num = 1; //contador para referencia das musicas
      num += 1;
      if (num == 9) //parametro de comparação se terminou as musicas
        num = 1;
      ctr.pause(); //para a musica que estava tocando
      document.getElementById('aqui').src = "musicas/" + num + ".mp3"; //muda o 'src' para outra musica
      ctr.load(); ///Muito necessario para poder carregar a musica nova
      ctr.play();


    }, false);

    vmenos.addEventListener('click', function() {
      ctr.play();
      ctr.volume -= 0.25;
    }, false);
  };
}
window.onload = init;
HTML
```

```html
<body>

  <h1> AUDIO HTML5</h1>
  <section>
    <audio id="som">
      <source src="musicas/1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" id="aqui">

        <p>Seu navegador não suporta o elemento da HTML5.
          <br>Faça <a href="som.zip">download de som.zip</a>
        </p>
    </audio>
    <div id="fundo-controles">
      <input type="image" src="javaaudio/play.png" alt="play" id="play">
      <input type="image" src="javaaudio/pause.png" alt="pause" id="pause">
      <input type="image" src="javaaudio/vmais.png" alt="Volume+" id="vmais">
      <input type="image" src="javaaudio/vmenos.png" alt="volume-" id="vmenos">
      <input type="button" value="proximo" id="proxi">
    </div>

  </section>



</body>
```

Comment: Isso é uma resposta?